# How to find the sum of elements located at odd indices in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sum, indices

I know a similar question has been asked here before, but mine is slightly different. I want to write a function that takes a list of positive integers and returns the sum of the elements located at the odd indices. The catch is, I want to use only a for loop or a while loop.
Here's what I have so far:

```
def getSumOdds(aList):
for i in range(0, len(aList)):
    if i%2 == 0:
        pass
    if i%2 != 0:
        sum = sum + aList[i]
        return sum
```

However, when I enter this code into Python, I get an error saying builtins.UnboundLocalError: local variable 'sum' referenced before assignment. Does anyone know a better way to find the sum or how to fix the error message? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Watch out for naming your variables to be the same as built in functions. It'll mean you hide the function.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the problem you should initialize `sum` to zero after the `def`. Another thing is to `return` `sum` after the `for`, not within the last `if`.

(As this question is obviously about a homework, I would rather not discuss advanced methods to solve the problem itself.)

Comment: I'd say it's ok to answer homework questions if the OP has shown some effort. Clearly here they have.

Comment: @PaulRooney Absolutely, I mean that the code can be heavily optimized but that will unlikely help the OP at this point.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a generator (or list comprehension for that):

```
def getSumOdds(aList):
    return sum(aList[i] for i in range(1,len(aList),2))
```

(given *indexing* is supported (a `list` supports this)).

or you can, like [@MSeifert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42387277/how-to-find-the-sum-of-elements-located-at-odd-indices-in-python/42387355#comment71922922_42387355) says, use *slicing*:

```
def getSumOdds(aList):
    return sum(aList[1::2])
```

(given slicing is supported, not all collections do this)

that's all you need: `sum` is a builtin function.

In case `aList` is a generator (you cannot access the *i*-th element for instance), you can use `itertools.islice`:

```
from itertools import islice

def getSumOdds(aList):
    return sum(islice(aList,1,None,2))
```

You can also use this method for lists, etc. (as long as `aList` is iterable).

Or - again given indexing is supported - you can put it in a `for` loop:

```
def getSumOdds(aList):
    result = 0
    for i in range(1,len(aList),2):
        result += aList[i]
    return result
```

Comment: why not just `sum(aList[1::2])`?

Comment: @MSeifert: yeah given it is a list, slicing is an option as well. Will edit.

Comment: " I want to use only a for loop or a while loop" says the OP

Comment: @Chris_Rands: well list comprehension is some kind of `for` loop :).