# How to produce a list of odd indices from a number in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to produce a list containing only the odd indices of a Python integer number.

here is what I tried to do:

```
number = 5167460267890853
numberList = [num for num in str(number)]
oddIndex = [num for num in numberList if numberList.index(num) % 2 == 0]
print(oddIndex)
```

Output:

```
['5', '6', '4', '6', '0', '6', '8', '0', '8', '5']
```

Expected output:

```
['5', '6', '4', '0', '6', '8', '0', '5']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use string slicing with a step of `2`.
Convert the number to a string, take only the odd indices and than convert to a list.

Using the this approach on your attempt, you could try:

```
number = 5167460267890853
numberList = [num for num in str(number)]
numberList = numberList[::2]
```

or just use the `list` built-in function:

```
number = 5167460267890853
oddIndex = list(str(number)[::2])
```

Both yield the desired output.

Answers to a similar question also use similar technique [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42387277/how-to-find-the-sum-of-elements-located-at-odd-indices-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

`list.index()` will return the index of the first seen element in the list. You can use `enumerate()` instead like this example:

```
number = 5167460267890853
out = [num for k, num in enumerate(str(number)) if not (k % 2)]
print(out)
# ['5', '6', '4', '0', '6', '8', '0', '5']
```